# merge similar xml tags to single using regex

Tags: java, regex, xml

i have my xml tags as below

```
 <additionaPtahsType>receive</additionaPtahsType>
    <additionaPtahsType>send</additionaPtahsType>
    <additionaPtahsType>section</additionaPtahsType>
```

need regex to merge these xml tags as result below

receive|send|section

Comment: need output as <additionalPtahsType>receive|send|section</additionalPtahsType>

Comment: You should [edit] your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: **don't**.

---

Long answer: Instead of using Regex, use XML parser. Regex is not a viable solution to parse XML (or any markup language at all). See here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3005263)

---

Wrong answer: If it is only one XML tag you want to capture contents of, you can do this with regex, but it's highly discouraged. Simply wrap anything you want into a group, get all matches into a collection and then combine them with your pipe ('**|**') character. Look here: [Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/yrHUuL/1)

**Disclaimer:** this solution is very naive. If there would be any nested tags it will also match them, which is rather not the expected result. If there are wrong/incomplete tags - it won't work. That's why you should use a parser.